# How do I make arrays interact with each other?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble with a school assignment:

> Write a program to create two arrays namely asciiArray and
>   decimalArray of 52  elements each. In the asciiArray, store letters of
>   the English alphabet; both lower and  upper case letters. In the
>   decimalArray, store the corresponding decimal values of  each of the
>   letters in the specific position in the asciiArray. For example,  If
>   asciiArray[0] holds ‘A’ then decimalArray[0] will hold the value 65. 
>   Pass these arrays to a method displayDecValue. Inside the method,
>   prompt the user  to enter any of the letters of the English alphabet
>   and display the corresponding  decimal value.

I have some of the coding down, but I do not know how to make the arrays interact with each other and return the value. Sorry if this is simple; I have never done Java before.  We also can't use anything advanced to write the code (it's beginner's Java).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParallelArrays {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        char[] asciiArray = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                              'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                              'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
                              'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
                              'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        int[] decimalArray = {97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,
                              114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,
                              75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
        displayDecValue(asciiArray, decimalArray);
    }

    public static void displayDecValue(char [ ] ascii, int [ ] dec) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a letter (a-z or A-Z): ");

        ascii = input.next().charAt(0);

        dec[0] = (int)ascii[0];

        System.out.printf("Decimal value of %c is: " + dec[0], ascii);
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be making the arrays interact with each other, you'll instead write some code that interacts with both of the arrays in a consistent and expected way.

Comment: I know this is an assignment and you have to follow it, but realistically, you would never do this. With characters like this, you can probably get away with some sort of casting. For more complex data types, you would use a `Map` of some kind.

Comment: Arrays are purely passive -- they don't "do" anything.

Comment: What you've got to do is search the ascii array for a match, then print the corresponding dec array value.  This implies a loop.  And note that you should not be assigning anything TO either ascii or dec inside your displayDecValue method.

Comment: First figure out how to search "ascii" for a match to the input character (which SHOULD NOT be assigned to "ascii", but to a temporary `char` variable).  (And if you don't know what a "temporary" or "local" variable is, pay better attention in class next time!)

Comment: (Can't believe that anyone actually upvoted this question.)

Comment: assigned char value to hold user input, figuring out loop now

Answer (score 3):

Following are things which you should wonder

1) You are storing the input from the user into array variable ascii. What would happen here?

2) You are reassigning predefined dec array at index position 0, with ascii[0]. What does this mean?

3) How would you search for the char in the ascii array(Hint : loop) and match it with dec array?

4) Is the print statement following C or Java syntax?

Then you will be able to fix the code easily.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to manually feed decimal array values. you can do something like below.
if we convert or typecast char to int we will get decimal value of that character.

eg
      `int output= (int)'a';`// here output is 97 that equivalent to decimal value of character 'a'.

```
    int[] decimalArray = new int[asciiArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++) {
        decimalArray[i] = (int)asciiArray[i];
    }
```

the complete example is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParallelArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] asciiArray = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
                'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

        int[] decimalArray = new int[asciiArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++) {
            decimalArray[i] = (int)asciiArray[i];
        }
        displayDecValue(asciiArray, decimalArray);
    }

    public static void displayDecValue(char[] ascii, int[] dec) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a letter (a-z or A-Z): ");

        char inputChar = input.next().charAt(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < ascii.length; i++) {

            if (inputChar == ascii[i]) {
                System.out.printf("Decimal value of '" + ascii[i] + "' is: "
                        + dec[0]);
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```